# Why does Times @@@ {{}} give {1}?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

```
Table @@@ FactorInteger[120] // Flatten;
Times @@@ DeleteDuplicates[Subsets[%]]

{1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 10, 15, 8, 12, 20, 30, 24, 40, 60, 120}
```

why does it start with 1 instead of just all combinations of the prime factors?

Comment: Because `Times[]` evaluates to the identity element of multiplication, just the same as `Plus[]` evaluates to the identity element of addition (i.e. `0`).  What would you have it evaluate to?

Comment: ok... so I'll just Drop[%,1], thanks

Comment: Or you can use `Subsets[..., {1, Infinity}]` or you can use `Rest`.

Comment: Another note: here you seem to be implementing `Divisors`.  Use it, if that's what you need.  In this context, including `1` makes perfect sense, as it is also a divisor.  Otherwise use `Rest@Divisors[n]`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Times @@@ {{}}` becomes `{Times[]}` so this question may be reduced to:

- why does `Times[]` evaluate to `1`?

This is the [`Default`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html) value of the `Times` operator:

```
Default[Times]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

This is mathematically logical and programmatically efficient.  This tutorial gives some examples:

- [Optional and Default Arguments](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionalAndDefaultArguments.html)

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're trying to get all divisors of 120. 1 *is* a divisor of 120, so why would you want to drop it?

This is just one example of how "Subsets" result including $\emptyset$ is perfectly aligned with the things people use it for.